# How to monitor the Azure data sync process in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azureportal, azure-data-sync

I am using Azure Data Sync to load data from one database to another. I want to monitor the performance and the resource consumption of the data sync between the two databases. 
I know that Azure portal has some monitoring tools but how can I use it to check the data sync process in particular? Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is to use Log Analytics to monitor Azure Data Sync as explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/monitoring-azure-sql-data-sync-using-oms-log-analytics/). It will provide you a dashboard to monitor Azure SQL Data Sync as shown below.

[image]

Log Analytics will also provide you e-mail notifications as shown below:

[image]

For detailed information about how to configure this solution, you can visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-monitor-oms) documentation.

In addition you can have metrics about CPU usage, Log IO, storage spaces of your Azure SQL Databases if you monitor it with Azure Monitor (the new name of Azure Log Analytics). For more information visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/azure-sql) documentation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will it include memory usage and CPU usage as well?

Comment: Add the whole Azure SQL Database to Azure Monitor = Log Analytics using this documenation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/azure-sql